Brightness issue on laptop since upgrading to 24.04
I upgraded my Ubuntu Budgie to 24.04 yesterday. I now have a weird bug that I did not have before: the display of the laptop randomly switches from normal brightness to very low brightness (to the point where I can read almost nothing). I do not understand what causes the display to switch.
Drivers: I updated the drivers using ubuntu-drivers. I have the nvidia 550.107.02 driver.
Here is the result of lshw -short.
=========================================================
                                  system      Computer
/0                                bus         Motherboard
/0/0                              memory      15GiB System memory
/0/1                              processor   AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Grap
/0/100                            bridge      Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                        generic     Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
/0/100/1.1                        bridge      Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.1/0                      display     GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / 
/0/100/1.1/0.1    card0           multimedia  GA104 High Definition Audio Contro
/0/100/1.1/0.1/0  input12         input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1.1/0.1/1  input13         input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1.1/0.1/2  input14         input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1.1/0.1/3  input15         input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/1.2                        bridge      Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0      eno1            network     RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express
/0/100/2.1                        bridge      Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/2.1/0      wlo1            network     Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/2.2                        bridge      Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/2.2/0      mmc0            bus         GL9750 SD Host Controller
/0/100/2.4                        bridge      Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/2.4/0      /dev/nvme0      storage     SK hynix PC711 HFS512GDE9X073N
/0/100/2.4/0/0    hwmon3          disk        NVMe disk
/0/100/2.4/0/2    /dev/ng0n1      disk        NVMe disk
/0/100/2.4/0/1    /dev/nvme0n1    disk        NVMe disk
/0/100/8.1                        bridge      Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to
/0/100/8.1/0      /dev/fb0        display     Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Rade
/0/100/8.1/0.2                    generic     Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platfo
/0/100/8.1/0.3                    bus         Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
/0/100/8.1/0.4                    bus         Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
/0/100/8.1/0.5    card2           multimedia  ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
/0/100/8.1/0.6    card1           multimedia  Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.6/0  input16         input       HD-Audio Generic Mic
/0/100/8.1/0.6/1  input17         input       HD-Audio Generic Headphone
/0/100/8.2                        bridge      Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to
/0/100/8.2/0                      storage     FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/14                         bus         FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                       bridge      FCH LPC Bridge
/0/100/14.3/0                     system      PnP device PNP0c01
/0/100/14.3/1                     system      PnP device PNP0b00
/0/100/14.3/2                     generic     PnP device HPQ8001
/0/100/14.3/3                     system      PnP device PNP0c02
/0/101                            bridge      Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/102                            bridge      Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/103                            bridge      Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/104                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
/0/105                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
/0/106                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
/0/107                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
/0/108                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
/0/109                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
/0/10a                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
/0/10b                            bridge      Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
/1                input0          input       Power Button
/2                input1          input       Lid Switch
/3                input11         input       HP WMI hotkeys
/4                input2          input       Power Button
/5                input22         input       Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master
/6                input26         input       Cobalt (AVRCP)
/7                input3          input       AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/8                input4          input       Video Bus
/9                input8          input       SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17 Mouse
/a                input9          input       SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17 Touchpad


I have the same issue with a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.1. I have brightness at 219 (set through keyboard) and sometimes actual_brightness sets itself to 96. I don't know why. AMD+Nvidia with driver 550.
